# What is the physical significance of fourier transforming a potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermis-golden-rule

Fermi's golden rule essentially states that the transfer rate between two plane waves is proportional to the Fourier transform of the potential (with respect to the difference in momenta).
What actually is the significance of the momentum space potential? Does it just imply the couplings between two arbitrary momentum states?

Answer (score 1):

The Golden Rule has you compute

$$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\mid #1 \rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1 \mid}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1 \mid}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\langle #1 \mid #2 \rangle}
|\bra{p_i}\hat{V}\ket{p_f}|^2,$$

where $p_i$ and $p_f$ are respectively the initial and final momentum in the case you consider. You can then introduce the closure relation for $\ket{x}$,

$$\bra{p_i}V\ket{p_f}\propto\int d^3x\,d^3y\ \braket{p_i}{x}\underbrace{\bra{x}\hat{V}\ket{y}}_{\displaystyle V(x)\delta(x-y)}\braket{y}{p_f}\propto\int d^3x\ V(x)e^{i(p_f-p_i)\cdot x},$$

where I did not bother writing the normalisations (and $\hbar=1$).
Hence the apparition of the Fourier transform.